# Box sorting Algorithm proof

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

i wrote a different proof for the box sorting algorithm in O(n^2) and proved it by induction.

can someone please refute/provide another proof to the solution?

The Problem-

You are given a set of n types of rectangular 3-D boxes, where the i^th box has height h(i), width w(i) and depth d(i) (all real numbers). all the lengths are different, and widths are different.You want to create a stack of boxes which is as tall as possible, but you can only stack a box on top of another box if the dimensions of the 2-D base of the lower box are each strictly larger than those of the 2-D base of the higher box.you can NOT rotate a box so that any side functions as its base.

the known solution-

Sort the boxes by ascending base area .
Create a table t of size n indexed by 1 ≤ i ≤ n. Starting with i = n to 1, define t[i] by max { h(i) , max { h(i) + t[j]} for all j>i such that w(j)>w(i) and l(j)>l(i)}
Return the following value: max {t[1], . . . , t[n]}
my solution -

sort the boxes by ascending width in array W, and by ascending length in array L.
create a nxn matrix, where t[i,j] = tallest possible stack built on a L(i) long and W(j) wide base.
the answer will be in t[n,n] since that is our max possible base area.
for the first row in the matrix (this is the tallest stack that can be built on the minimum length base area - meaning only the box with the minimum length can be in it)

define t[1,j]:

0 <-- if W(j) < width of the box with min length

height of the box with lowest length <-- if W(j) >= width of the box

for the first column in the matrix (this is the tallest stack that can be built on the minimum width base area - meaning only the box with the minimum width can be in it)

define t[i,1]:

0 <-- if L(i) < length of the box with min width
height of the box with lowest width <-- if L(i) >= length of the box with min width
define t[i,j] = height of the box whose length is L(i) and width is W(j) , if such exist + max { t[i-1,j] , t[i,j-1] }

there can only be one box with those attributes since they are all unique.
thank you all!

Comment: If *no rotation* of boxes is allowed at all, then you have a partial ordering of boxes $B_i \le B_j$ that relates which can be placed atop another. Using box *heights* as vertex weights, you seek a maximum sum of weights path in the corresponding graph.

Comment: thank you, but what i want to know is if my solution is correct, i'm aware of other solutions.